# Integral Calculus - Find Volume

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Find the volume of solid generated by rotating region created by $x$-axis and $y=4\sec(x)$ between $x=0$ and $x=1$.

Why is the answer $16 \pi$? I get $16\pi\tan(1)$:

$\pi\int_0^1(4\sec(x))^2 = 16\pi\int_0^1\sec^2x = 16\pi 
 \tan(x)\vert_0^1 = 16\pi \tan(1) - 16\pi \tan(0) = 16\pi \tan (1)$

What am I missing in this problem?

Comment: nothing. seems good

Comment: $x=0$ to $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$ would give $16\pi$ so the error could be in the question or the answer given.